# Spring Data Rest Unit Tests Selectively Pass

Tags: java, spring, dbunit, spring-data-rest, spring-test-dbunit

I am investigating the use of Spring Data Rest (2.0.1.RELEASE and Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE), and have written a simple service. I have also written a simple test class (see below) using DbUnit.

Unfortunately when I run the tests only the findAll method passes. If I comment out the findAll method then the findInvestigationalProductById passes and directLink fails. If I then comment out findInvestigationalProductById then directLink passes.

None of these methods changes data state, so I would like to know if there is some configuration I have overlooked that can cause this behaviour.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/com/perceptive/ctms/core/tests-context.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
                          DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup("investigational-products-data.xml")
public class InvestigationalProductTests {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void findAll() throws Exception {
    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/investProduct"))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(content().contentType("application/hal+json"));
    resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$_embedded.investigationalProduct", hasSize(3)));
    resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$_embedded.investigationalProduct[0].investigationalProductCode", is("ACTIVE1")));
    resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$_embedded.investigationalProduct[1].investigationalProductCode", is("ACTIVE2")));
    resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$_embedded.investigationalProduct[2].investigationalProductCode", is("ACTIVE3")));
  }

  @Test
  public void directLink() throws Exception {
    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/investProduct/3"))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(content().contentType("application/hal+json"));
    System.out.println(resultActions);
    resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$investigationalProductCode", is("ACTIVE3")));
  }

  @Test
  public void findInvestigationalProductById() throws Exception {
    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/investProduct/search/findInvestigationalProductById?id=3"))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(content().contentType("application/hal+json"));
    resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$_embedded.investigationalProduct", hasSize(1)));
    resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("$_embedded.investigationalProduct[0].developmentName", is("developmentName3")));
  }
}
```

Comment: should the webAppContextSetup be in the method @BeforeClass

Comment: I used `@Before` because all the examples I could find seemed to use that approach. `@BeforeClass` would be awkward as the method would need to be static and I couldn't use autowiring for the WebApplicationContext, but I'll see if something is doable.

Comment: I've tried moving the setup to `@BeforeClass`, but cannot find a way of getting the necessary `WebApplicationContext`.

Comment: I'm not able to check this for a few days, but I suspect `@DatabaseSetup` doesn't work how I was expecting. I think it probably deletes and then recreates the data before each test. Since my table's id is automatically generated this results in the first test using ids 1 to 3, the second ids 4 to 6 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding about how `@DatabaseSetup` works. The problem tests are all dealing with referencing data by a generated id. The [API](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/apidocs/com/github/springtestdbunit/annotation/DatabaseSetup.html) states:

> Test annotation which indicates how to put a database into a know
>   state before tests are run. This annotation can be placed on a class
>   or on methods. When placed on a class the setup is applied before each
>   test methods is executed.

which to my mind is a little ambiguous, but [additional documentation](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/) states:

> By default setup will perform a CLEAN_INSERT operation, this means
>   that all data from tables referenced in the DataSet XML will be
>   removed before inserting new rows.

i.e. tests should not assume that the database (including any sequence numbers) is put into a clean state, just that the data is clean.

Adding the following code

```
  private static int currentOffset = 0;
  private static final int TEST_OFFSET = 3;

  /**
   * After each test is run DatabaseSetup annotation deletes records 
   * and inserts fresh ones - this means we need to keep track of the 
   * current offset
   */
   @After
   public void offset() {
     currentOffset += TEST_OFFSET;
   }
```

(with occasional modifications to currentOffset when testing inserts) can keep track of the current ids.

This does not seems ideal, but I do not know a way of resetting the database to a truly clean state.